# onkeypress on a <a> tag

Tags: javascript, onkeypress

I'm trying get my `<a>` tag triggered when the user press on the "enter" key. `(onkeypress)`.

my `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="javascript:search()" onkeypress="return runScript(event)">
```

this is my **javascript** :

```
 function runScript(e)
   {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                alert("dssd");
        return false;

      }
   }
```

I dont know whats messed up ?

Comment: hiya, quick suggestion: whats that href which javascript in it? try it without href please. hope this helps - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp ; can you also try putting alert or debugger to see if your run script is getting invoked, if you JSFiddle it I can see how we can knock this thing down. cheers

Comment: if I comment the "href" its still wont work..

Comment: sorry man - i meant put # instead of javascript search - but seems you got it working.

Comment: Why are you using an A element at all? They're meant to be anchors or links, not buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its work for me

```
 <a href="javascript:search();"  onkeypress="return runScript(event);">Open in new window using javascript</a>
```

**javaScript**

```
 window.runScript = function (e) {

       if (e.keyCode == 13) {
           alert('ss');
           return false;
       }
       else {

           return true;
       }
   }

   window.search = function () {
       alert('s');
   }
```

**live demo** : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kCQVc/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Write your html as given below. Note the property `tabindex` which makes the a tag focusable in certain browsers.

```
<a id="link" href="http://google.com" onkeydown="runScript(event)" tabindex="1">I am a link</a>
```

If you need an autofocus on load, you can use the jQuery function `focus` as shown below.

```
$(document).ready(
    function(e){
        $("#link").focus();
    }
);
```

Then your function

```
function runScript(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
       alert("pressed enter key");
    }
}
```

you have to call `e.preventDefault();` (or return false in some browsers) if you want to prevent the link load the link in href.

```
function runScript(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
       alert("pressed enter key");
    }
    return false;
}
```

see a demo here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/diode/hfJSn/9/show  press enter key when the page is loaded

Comment: Minor note: I believe you meant to suggest setting a tabindex of 0, not 1. Zero will ensure the element is both tabbable and focusable, -1 will make it focusable but not tabbable, and any number over 0 declares an explicit position in the tab sequence, which is rarely desireable.

Answer (score 2):

The ENTER key actually triggers the onclick event:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('hello!');">
```

This means that your search() function inside the href will execute before the onkeypress event.

Answer (score 1):

That works in my browser, though I suspect it's not the way to achieve what you actually want to do... (maybe?)

Number one, you probably don't want it to "`return`" anything, so you can just do `onkeypress="runScript(e)"` and it'll run. If that function does return a value, it's not gonna go anywhere...

Number two, it's kinda rare that a keydown event would fire on an anchor (`<a>`) element, unless of course the user tabs through the other elements 'till it has focus and then presses a key (usually the browser will "highlight" the element that currently has keyboard focus, if it's not just the whole page). Are you wanting your script to run when someone presses enter after typing in a search box or something? if so, you probably want to listen for the event on the search box itself, so add it as that element's onkeydown attribute (for example: `<input id="mySearchBox" onkeydown="runScript(e)">`) if you just want it to run whenever the user presses enter, regardless of focus or typing text into any particular field, just do as edmastermind29's comment said and add the event listener to the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this to your script?

`document.onkeypress = runScript;`