# How to capture Enter key press?

Tags: javascript, textbox, keypress, dom-events, onkeypress

In my HTML page, I had a textbox for user to input keyword for searching. When they click the search button, the JavaScript function will generate a URL and run in new window.

The JavaScript function work properly when the user clicks the search button by mouse, but there is no response when the user presses the ENTER key.

```javascript
function searching(){
    var keywordsStr = document.getElementById('keywords').value;
    var cmd ="http://XXX/advancedsearch_result.asp?language=ENG&+"+ encodeURI(keywordsStr) + "&x=11&y=4";
    window.location = cmd;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1" method="get">
    <input name="keywords" type="text" id="keywords" size="50" >
    <input type="submit" name="btn_search" id="btn_search" value="Search" 
        onClick="javascript:searching(); return false;" onKeyPress="javascript:searching(); return false;">
    <input type="reset" name="btn_reset" id="btn_reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Hope this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653382/onkeypress-on-a-a-tag

Comment: The javascript: shoudl not be used in the onClick or onKeyPress attributes

Answer (score 117, accepted):

### Form approach

As scoota269 says, you should use `onSubmit` instead, cause pressing enter on a textbox will most likey trigger a form submit (if inside a form)

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="handle">
    <input type="text" name="txt" />
</form>

<script>
    function handle(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // Otherwise the form will be submitted

        alert("FORM WAS SUBMITTED");
    }
</script>
```

### Textbox approach

If you want to have an event on the input-field then you need to make sure your `handle()` will return false, otherwise the form will get submitted.

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" name="txt" onkeypress="handle(event)" />
</form>

<script>
    function handle(e){
        if(e.keyCode === 13){
            e.preventDefault(); // Ensure it is only this code that runs

            alert("Enter was pressed was presses");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Error page while accessing JSFiddle

Comment: Weird.. But the JS-Fiddle did only for his specific scenario. The code examples in the answer is the main idea..

Comment: You need to pass the event as a parameter. 
<input type="text" name="txt" onkeypress="handle(event)" />

Comment: thanks @TryingToImprove for this Idea.

Comment: Please note that e.keyCode is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Answer (score 39):

Use `onkeypress` . Check if the pressed key is enter (keyCode = 13). if yes, call the `searching()` function.

**HTML**

```
<input name="keywords" type="text" id="keywords" size="50"  onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event)">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function handleKeyPress(e){
 var key=e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (key==13){
     searching();
  }
}
```

Here is a snippet showing it in action:

```js
document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = "Default";
function handle(e){
 document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = "Trigger";
 var key=e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (key==13){
     document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = "HELLO!";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="box22" value="please" onkeypress="handle(event)"/>
<div id="msg1"></div>
```

Comment: It did not work for me either what could be the reason?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. The issue is because javascript is not ready by the time windows get loaded. You can either use document.ready function (of jquery). or select "no wrap-in body" dropdown option in javascript settings and it should work. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ezrwe/35/ .

Answer (score 13):

Use `event.key` instead of `event.keyCode`!

```
function onEvent(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        // Submit form
    }
};
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Comment: This is helpful, but not currently a complete answer. Could you flesh it out with full context?

Comment: @bob event.keyCode is deprecated and event.key is now preferred

Answer (score 7):

Try this....

HTML inline

```
onKeydown="Javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) fnsearch();"
or
onkeypress="Javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) fnsearch();"
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
function fnsearch()
{
   alert('you press enter');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use javascript

```
ctl.attachEvent('onkeydown', function(event) {

        try {
            if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                FieldValueChanged(ctl.id, ctl.value);
            }
            false;
        } catch (e) { };
        return true
    })
```

Answer (score 4):

Small bit of generic jQuery for you..

```
$('div.search-box input[type=text]').on('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(this).parent().find('input[type=submit]').trigger('click');
        return false;
     }
});
```

This works on the assumes that the textbox and submit button are wrapped on the same div. works a treat with multiple search boxes on a page

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a handler for the `onkeypress` action.

**HTML**

```
<input name="keywords" type="text" id="keywords" size="50" onkeypress="handleEnter(this, event)" />
```

**JS**

```
function handleEnter(inField, e)
{
    var charCode;

    //Get key code (support for all browsers)
    if(e && e.which)
    {
        charCode = e.which;
    }
    else if(window.event)
    {
        e = window.event;
        charCode = e.keyCode;
    }

    if(charCode == 13)
    {
       //Call your submit function
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it with a JSFiddle, but it didn't work for me. http://jsfiddle.net/94jsv/

Answer (score 1):

Use an onsubmit attribute on the form tag rather than onclick on the submit.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 // jquery press check by Abdelhamed Mohamed


    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("textarea").keydown(function(event){
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
         // do something here
         alert("You Pres Enter");
        }
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: I love the fact that you felt that this incredibly simple piece of code was worthy of attribution!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="txt" onkeypress="handle" />
</form>






<script>
    $("#txtBox").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                alert("Enter was pressed was presses");
            }

            return false;
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is simple ES-6 style answer. For capturing an "enter" key press and executing some function

```
<input
    onPressEnter={e => (e.keyCode === 13) && someFunc()}
/>
```