# Linking keys to code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm quite new to programming (started yesterday) and so far I've just created a very simple code. I am currently unaware on how to make it so I can click enter and it will submit the forum post so any commands on how to make that possible would be greatly appreciated :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title Changing Simulator!</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function substitute()  {
var myValue = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value;

if (myValue.length == 0)   {
alert('Please enter a real value in the text box!');
return;
}  
var myTitle = document.getElementById('title');
myTitle.innerHTML = myValue;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="title">Title Changing Simulator!</h1>

<input type="text" id="myTextBox" />
<input type="submit" value="Click My Button" onclick="substitute()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Go to CodeSchool.com and take one of their free courses on web programming. Rails for Zombies is a good choice, or the one for Node.  You need to have some kind of server-side logic that gets the info you're trying to post.  One of those courses will help with the fundamentals. Good luck

Comment: This updates the title h1 element.  What were you trying to accomplish?

Comment: with 'click enter', you mean 'type enter', right?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your input and button in a `<form>` and listen for the form's [submit](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp) event which is triggered either by clicking the submit button or pressing enter in the input field. See also [How to trigger enter key press of textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987300/how-to-trigger-enter-key-press-of-textbox)

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const text = document.getElementById('text');
const title = document.getElementById('title');

form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (text.value.length > 0) {
    title.textContent = text.value;
  } else {
    alert('Please enter a real value in the text box!');
  }
});
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Title Changing Simulator!</h1>

<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```