# How can I use Enter Key instead of clicking the button by switch

Tags: javascript, html

I need to use Enter key to trigger my button. it should call function greetings().

HTML

```
<input id='input' />
    <button onclick='greetings()' id='btn' class="button button5">OK</button>
```

Javascript

```
function greetings(){
  let name=document.getElementById('input').value;
  if(document.getElementById('input').value.length!==0){
    console.log(document.getElementById('input').value.length);
    document.getElementById("hed").innerHTML="Hello "+name;

  }
  else{

    document.getElementById("hed").innerHTML='';
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture Enter key press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987300/how-to-capture-enter-key-press)

Answer (score 2):

You have to attach the event to the document:

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
            if (e.key === "Enter"){
              //do your stuff
            }
        }, false);
```

Please note the use of `e.key`, do not use `e.keyCode` cause it's [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

Answer (score 0):

#### KeyboardEvent.code

> The KeyboardEvent.code property represents a physical key on the
>   keyboard (as opposed to the character generated by pressing the key).
>   In other words, this property returns a value which isn't altered by
>   keyboard layout or the state of the modifier keys. [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)

You need to listen to `keydown` or `keyup` events and then check if the `event.code` is `Enter`.

```js
function greetings() {
  let name = document.getElementById('input');
  let text = document.getElementById("hed");
  if (name !== 0) {
   text.innerHTML = "Hello " + name.value;
  } else {
    text.innerHTML = '';
  }
}

const body = document.querySelector("body");
body.onkeyup = function(event) {
  console.log("event", event.code)
  if (event.code === "Enter") {
    greetings()   
  }
};
```

```html
<input id="input">
<p id="hed"></p>
```

#### Update

It is better to use `event.code` instead of `event.key` since it represents a physical key on the keyboard, not the generated character. Run this code snippet.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  let str = "KeyboardEvent: key='" + event.key + "' | code='" +
            event.code + "'";
  let el = document.createElement("span");
  el.innerHTML = str + "<br/>";
 
  document.getElementById("output").appendChild(el);
}, true);
```

```css
#output {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Credit:</strong>Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code </p>

<hr>

<p>Press keys on the keyboard to see what the KeyboardEvent's key and code
   values are for each one.</p>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the running working code snippet, as you required, ENJOY

```js
function greetings(){
  var name=document.getElementById('input').value;
  if(document.getElementById('input').value.length!==0){
    console.log(document.getElementById('input').value.length);
    document.getElementById("hed").innerHTML="Hello "+name;

  }
  else{

    document.getElementById("hed").innerHTML='';
  }

}

document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
            if (e.key === "Enter" || e.which == 13){
              greetings();
            }
        }, false);
```

```html
<input id='input' />
    <button onclick='greetings()' id='btn' class="button button5">OK</button>
    <p id="hed"></p>
```