# How to trigger a submit action for an input element or form while pressing enter key?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have a simple search bar (input field) which should trigger an onSubmit action while we press Enter button

Comment: use onKeyPress: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827234/how-to-handle-the-onkeypress-event-in-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

You can use onKeyPress.
Check this : `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987300/how-to-capture-enter-key-press`

Answer (score 0):

Simple, have a button type submit inside the form. Here's an example:

```
const onSubmit = () => {}
// ..
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  ...
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
  ...
</form>
```

You don't need to use onKeyPress event.

Comment: but if the seacrh bar isn't inside the form?

Comment: You can have an id on form `<form id="search-form" />`. Then the input or any element can part of the form with form attribute: `<input form="search-form" type="search"...`.